# Prove that $ |\tan(b) - \tan(a)| \geq \left|b - a\right|, \forall a, b \in (\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}) $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I want to prove that $ \left|\tan(b) - \tan(a)\right| \geq \left|b - a\right|, \forall a, b \in (\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}) $, is my proof valid?

Let $ a \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}) $ and define a function $ f : \left[a, \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \to \mathbb{R} $, $ f(x) = \tan(x) - \tan(a) - x + a $.

Notice that $ f(a) = \tan(a) -\tan(a) - a + a = 0$.

$ f $ is differentiable as the sum of differentiable functions. $ \frac{d}{dx} f(x) = \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)} - 1 $.

For every $ x \in \left[a, \frac{\pi}{2}\right), 0 \leq \cos^2(x) \leq1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}-1\geq 0 \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}f(x) \geq 0 \Rightarrow f$ is not decreasing, and therefore for every $ x \in \left[a, \frac{\pi}{2}\right), f(x) \geq f(a) = 0 $.

Let $ b, c \in \left(\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right) $ and assume $ b \gt c $. Therefore, $ \tan(b) - \tan(c) \geq b -c $ and because $ \tan(x)$ and $ x $ are increasing on this interval, $ \tan(b) - \tan(c) = \left|\tan(b) - \tan(c)\right|, b -c = \left|b -c \right| $ and therefore $ \left|\tan(b) - \tan(c)\right| \geq \left|b-c\right| $.

Comment: Your proof is correct, but a shorter one would be to apply the MVT to $\tan.$

Comment: Geometrically, if we identify $a$ and $b$ with points on the unit circle to the right of the $y$-axis, then $|b - a|/2$ is the area of the circular sector between the radii from the origin to $a$ and $b,$ and $|\tan b - \tan a|/2$ is the area of the triangle formed by extending the two radii to meet the vertical tangent line $x = 1.$

Answer (score 4):

We want to prove that $|\tan(b) - \tan(a)| \geq |b-a|$ for all $a,b \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

First, note that $\tan(x)$ is continuous and differentiable on $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, so by the mean value theorem, there exists a point $c$ between $a$ and $b$ such that:

$$\tan(b) - \tan(a) = \sec^2(c)(b-a).$$

Taking absolute values of both sides and using the fact that $\sec^2(x) \geq 1$ for all $x$, we obtain:

$$|\tan(b) - \tan(a)| \geq |b-a|.$$

Therefore, we have shown that $|\tan(b) - \tan(a)| \geq |b-a|$ for all $a,b \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, as desired.

Comment: You can shorten "$\tan(x)$ is continuous and differentiable" to just  "$\tan(x)$ is differentiable", because differentiable implies continuous.